# How to print the sum of types in a record in F#?

Tags: list, math, f#, sum, record

I have the below record for how many items were sold at a shop:

```
type ShopEarnings = { Item: string;    Price: int; Quantity: int}
let pencils =       { Item= "Pencils"; Price = 2;  Quantity = 500 }
let pens =          { Item= "Pens";    Price = 5;  Quantity = 200 }
let labels =        { Item= "Labels";  Price = 3;  Quantity = 300 }
let rulers =        { Item= "Rulers";  Price = 5;  Quantity = 100 }
```

I want to calculate the total amount of items sold so I can print something like:

`printfn "%i items were sold" totalItemsSold`

and it will output

> 1100 items were sold

Also, I should not need to enter the items for addition manually in case there are 100 items.

I tried different approaches like List.sum but it would not work.
What would be the best way to calculate the total sum of "Quantity"?

Answer (score 4):

`List.sumBy` will do it:

```ml
let totalItemsSold =
    [pencils; pens; labels; rulers]
        |> List.sumBy (fun earnings -> earnings.Quantity)
printfn "%i items were sold" totalItemsSold
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I did not want to enter the functions manually because there could be 100 functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "functions". Do you mean that you don't want to create the list of records manually, like I did? If you have 100 records, are they in a database? Or do you really have 100 hardcoded records, each bound to its own name, like in your example? In any case, you'll need some way to put the records into a list or sequence in order to compute the sum.

Comment: They will be hardcoded for now like the 5 above. Yes, I am trying to put it in a list.